# Create Unique Index on a table with duplicate rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-indexes

I have a table which has a UNIQUE INDEX on 6 different columns. However, there are duplicates in the table. When I drop the index and try to re-create it, it throws error saying there are duplicate values.

Is there a way in which I can have the duplicate rows and still create the unique index ?

I see that there are NOVALIDATE options for constraints. Is there anything similar for Indexes.

I am guessing there should be a way since there duplicate rows in the table with a valid UNIQUE INDEX.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Could you please explain why my question was down voted. I can re-phrase the question or add details if you could point out the problem. I genuinely need assistance.

Comment: do you want to prevent getting error during multiple insert operations  even violation for uniqueness occurs?

Comment: I want the unique index to be enforced in future. Right now I have duplicates. My problem is creating the unique index by getting to not be enforced on the records I have.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a UNIQUE index on your table, even if it has duplicates, if you mark the index as UNUSABLE. This means that the index will exist but the system can't make use of it. To do so use a command similar to

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNUSABLE_UNIQUE_IDX_SUCCEEDS
  ON TABLE_WITH_DUPS(ID)
  UNUSABLE
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6ab452230299ff89069cdba32e0293ef)

[CREATE INDEX docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF01209)

Answer (score 0):

As if you don't want to get error `ORA-00001 Unique constraint violated` error during multiple insert operations even violation occurs **unless** the inserted data **commited**. Then you can make the unique key `deferrable initially deferred` such as

```
alter table tab
  drop constraint Ukey [cascade]; 

alter table tab
  add constraint Ukey unique ( col1, col2, ..., col6 )
  deferrable initially deferred
```

the above `cascade` option is related to removing the unique key even if there  exist foreign keys in the child tables of the table tab.

Comment: I have a Unique Index, not a Constraint.

Comment: well, you can try like this, since if you create a unique constraint, then a unique index already being created @learner .

Comment: I do not have the permissions to add new constraints.  It won't be agreed to. But I just wonder how it was possible to get duplicate records and still manage to have unique index in the first place.